# How best to distinguish between "available", "not yet available" and "will never become available"?

Tags: games, application-state

In Team Fortress 2, the Engineer can construct buildings. He can build one of each type of building, and they cost different amounts of Metal to build. Therefore, the buildings on his menu can be in one of three states:

- Able to build
- Unable to build because not enough metal
- Unable to build because already built

Here is how the default HUD looks:

[image: Sentry already built, Dispenser available to build, Teleporters not enough metal]

I always find that I have to read carefully to find the reason, not a good idea in the heat of battle.

This is how my custom HUD, rayshud, does it:

[image: Another image]

It just increases the font size. Clipping issues aside, I think a larger font helps a little here, but not much.

Here is how another custom HUD, BWHud, does it:

[image: BWHud]

This one is just weird.

So what's the best way to contrast these states? I'd say perhaps only show the buildings that can be built, but that doesn't appear to be an option.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I interpret your question:

- How do I show a choice that's already been used?

Once it's been used, make it disappear. Or, if you need to convey additional information about the choice that's already been used, change its visual appearance.

If you don't want to make it disappear, you could change the "already used" choice visually:

[image]

Comment: There are actually four possibilities here:

Available; Not yet available; no longer available (used); never available. I would hide "never available" but display the other three as suggested above. Very nice!